# Find the largest angle for which sine and tangent agree to within two significant figures.

Tags: trigonometry

I am kind of stuck with the solving process of this question:

\begin{align}
& \text{error } = 0.01 \\
\implies & \tan\theta = \text{ error }+ \sin\theta \\
\implies & \tan\theta = 0.01 + \sin\theta \\
\implies & \tan\theta - \sin\theta = 0.01 \\
\implies & \dfrac {\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}  - \sin\theta = 0.01
\end{align}
And this is where I stop, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Do you mean the largest angle less than $\pi/2$?  Otherwise, $\sin(n \pi) = \tan(n \pi) = 0$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: I suspect that this is just a numerical problem, and you just plot |tan $\theta$ - sin $\theta$| until this is equal to 0.01

Comment: Also "agree to within two significant figures" is not the same as a difference of $0.01$.

Comment: In the old days (not too long ago) we used tables: http://math2.org/math/trig/tables.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It $\sin(\theta) = x \in (0,\pi/2)$, $\tan(\theta) = x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  The equation $\tan(\theta) - \sin(\theta) = r$ then implies
$${x}^{4}+2\,r{x}^{3}+{r}^{2}{x}^{2}-2\,rx-{r}^{2} = 0$$
For $r = 1/100$ this is irreducible.  It does have closed-form solutions in terms of radicals, but they are not pleasant.  Numerical methods can be used.

Comment: It can be slightly simplified by using $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ substitution, we end up with $t^4+400t^3-1=0$ giving an approximate $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt[3]{400}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest value of $x$ is $\tan^{-1} 0.275$ **radians**, or something infinitely smaller than that.

Plotting the graph $round(100 \tan x) - round(100 \sin x)$ on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b2phip6ojv) gives many solutions, but the greatest solution that satisfies $x < \pi/2$ is approximately $0.26386$.

However, $\tan 0.26386$ $\approx 0.2749933$, and $\sin 0.26386 \approx 0.26515$. This suggests that $\tan x$ can get as close to $0.275$ as you want, and $\sin x$ will still round to $0.27$. However, once $\tan x$ is $0.275$, then it rounds to $0.28$, but $\sin x$ still rounds to $0.27$.

The idea of this formula is to round $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ to $2$ significant figures, and find $x$ where they are equal, or in other words, find the zeroes of $round(\tan x) - round(\sin x)$.

Since in Desmos, the function $round()$ rounds only to the nearest integer, then we can multiply by $100$, round it, and then divide back by  $100$, which results in $\frac{1}{100}(100 \ round(\tan x)$ $- 100\ round(\tan x)) = 0$, and simplifies to the formula above.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Israel gave the rigorous answer; the solution implies solving a quartic. Zwin gave also an approximation.

Just for the fun of it, let me give another one.

Assuming that $r$ and $x$ are small, we could use Taylor series giving
$$\tan(x)-\sin(x)=\frac{x^3}{2}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ then
$$\tan(x)-\sin(x)=r\implies \frac{x^3}{2}=r\implies x=\sqrt[3]{2r}\tag 1$$ which exactly Zwin's result.

We can do a little better, using, instead of Taylor series, [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) and get 
$$\tan(x)-\sin(x) \approx \frac{2 x^3}{4-x^2}$$ You will be amazed to see how close rhs and lhs are if you plot the two functions for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. So, using it
$$\tan(x)-\sin(x)=r\implies \frac{2 x^3}{4-x^2}=r\implies 2x^3+ rx^2-4 r=0$$

So, using approximations, we reduced the problem to a cubic equation which has the good idea to show only one real root. Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root), we get as an explicit solution
$$x=\frac{1}{3} r \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{216}{r^2}-1\right)\right)\tag 2$$

The pitty is that for your case, $(1)$ and $(2)$ lead to almost identical results.

**Edit**

By analogy with the result from $(1)$, let us assume that we can write
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n\left(\sqrt[3]{2r}\right)^n$$ and use Taylor series for the expansion of $\tan(x)-\sin(x)=r$ around $r=0$. This leads to
$$a_1=1 \qquad a_3=-\frac{1}{12}\qquad a_5=-\frac{1}{120}\qquad a_7=\frac{1}{336}\qquad a_9=\frac{1}{2304}$$ all even coefficients being $0$.

As shown in the table below, the results are extremly good even for "large" values of $r$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 r& \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.005 & 0.214606 & 0.214606  \\
 0.010 & 0.269763 & 0.269763  \\
 0.015 & 0.308200 & 0.308200  \\
 0.020 & 0.338625 & 0.338625  \\
 0.025 & 0.364183 & 0.364183  \\
 0.030 & 0.386414 & 0.386414  \\
 0.035 & 0.406202 & 0.406202  \\
 0.040 & 0.424105 & 0.424105  \\
 0.045 & 0.440501 & 0.440501  \\
 0.050 & 0.455660 & 0.455660  \\
 0.055 & 0.469783 & 0.469783  \\
 0.060 & 0.483021 & 0.483021  \\
 0.065 & 0.495495 & 0.495495  \\
 0.070 & 0.507300 & 0.507300  \\
 0.075 & 0.518513 & 0.518513  \\
 0.080 & 0.529200 & 0.529200  \\
 0.085 & 0.539414 & 0.539414  \\
 0.090 & 0.549200 & 0.549200  \\
 0.095 & 0.558598 & 0.558597  \\
 0.100 & 0.567640 & 0.567639  \\
 0.105 & 0.576356 & 0.576355  \\
 0.110 & 0.584771 & 0.584770  \\
 0.115 & 0.592908 & 0.592907  \\
 0.120 & 0.600787 & 0.600786  \\
 0.125 & 0.608424 & 0.608423  \\
 0.130 & 0.615837 & 0.615836  \\
 0.135 & 0.623039 & 0.623038  \\
 0.140 & 0.630043 & 0.630041  \\
 0.145 & 0.636861 & 0.636859  \\
 0.150 & 0.643504 & 0.643501  \\
 0.155 & 0.649980 & 0.649977  \\
 0.160 & 0.656299 & 0.656296  \\
 0.165 & 0.662469 & 0.662465  \\
 0.170 & 0.668497 & 0.668493  \\
 0.175 & 0.674390 & 0.674386  \\
 0.180 & 0.680155 & 0.680150  \\
 0.185 & 0.685797 & 0.685792  \\
 0.190 & 0.691323 & 0.691317  \\
 0.195 & 0.696736 & 0.696729  \\
 0.200 & 0.702042 & 0.702035
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Using zwin's suggestion, using $t=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$,
$$\tan(x)-\sin(x)-r=0\implies r t^4+4 t^3-r=0$$ We can solve the quartic equation with radicals (ugly/monstreous solutions) and develop the valid one as Taylor series around $r=0$. Using $z=\sqrt[3]{2r}$, this leads to
$$t=\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^5}{96}+\frac{z^9}{1536}-\frac{35 z^{13}}{663552}+\frac{77
   z^{17}}{15925248}+O\left(z^{21}\right)$$

Now, using $x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$ and repeating the expansion, we get

$$x=z-\frac{z^3}{12}-\frac{z^5}{120}+\frac{z^7}{336}+\frac{z^9}{2304}-\frac{5
   z^{11}}{25344}-\frac{35 z^{13}}{1078272}+\frac{z^{15}}{61440}+\frac{385
   z^{17}}{135364608}+O\left(z^{19}\right)$$

For $r=\frac 12$ that is to say $z=1$, the above expansion gives as an estimate $x=\frac{617563433269}{677499863040}\approx 0.911533$ while the "exact" solution would be $0.911531$.

For $r=\frac 1{100}$, this would lead to the approximation
$$x=0.269763141387359251$$ while the "exact" solution would be
$$x=0.269763141387359224$$